# Creating p2p connection iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, tcp, gcdasyncsocket

Okay. So I have been trying to connect devices p2p with streams for a week. Still no result and i am getting crazy and desperate. Please Don't send me to Ray Wenderlich tutorial and GCD wiki or to CFStream Guide as i have surfed it to the holes.

So 1) Variant Here i

1. Get Ip Of My device
2. Manually input ip in text field of other device
3. Init network communication on one device.
4. Error - connecting to host.

   ```
    + (NSString *)getIPAddress {

    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
   struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
   int success = 0;
   // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
    // Loop through linked list of interfaces
    temp_addr = interfaces;
     while(temp_addr != NULL) {
       if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
       // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
          if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
               // Get NSString from C String
               address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];

           }

       }

       temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
   }
    }
    // Free memory
   freeifaddrs(interfaces);
   return address;

   }
   ```

   - (void) initNetworkCommunication:(NSString*)ipToConnect {
     NSString *urlStr = ipToConnect;
     if (![urlStr isEqualToString:@""]) {
     NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
     if (!website) {
         NSLog(@"%@ is not a valid URL");
         return;
     }
     CFReadStreamRef readStream;
     CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
     CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)[website host], 80, &readStream, &writeStream);

   NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
   NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
   [inputStream setDelegate:self];
   [outputStream setDelegate:self];
   [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
   [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
   [inputStream open];
   [outputStream open];

   }

   - (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

   NSLog(@"stream event %lu", streamEvent);

   switch (streamEvent) {

   ```
   case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
       NSLog(@"Stream opened");
       break;
   case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

       if (theStream == inputStream) {

           uint8_t buffer[1024];
           int len;

           while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
               len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
               if (len > 0) {

                   NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                   if (nil != output) {

                       NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                       //[self messageReceived:output];

                   }
               }
           }
       }
       break;


   case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

       NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
       break;

   case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

       [theStream close];
       [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    //   [theStream release];
       theStream = nil;

       break;
   default:
       NSLog(@"Unknown event");
   ```

   }

   }

Variant 2 with GCD.
1. Same
2. Set both devices to listen to input

```
+(void)listenSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)listenSocket
{

listenSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![listenSocket acceptOnPort:80 error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"I goofed: %@", error);
}

}
```

3) Tried to connect with manually inputting IP

```
 +(void)connectToDeviceWithIp:(NSString*)deviceIp andSend:(HSUserCard*)tempCard andSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)tempSocket
{

tempSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
NSError *err = nil;
if (![tempSocket connectToHost:deviceIp onPort:80 error:&err])
    NSLog(@"I goofed: %@", err);



[tempSocket writeData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:tempCard] withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
}
```

4) Result nothing - i did put several breaks on every delegate function  =NOTHING.

Omg - i solved this task on Android in 20 minutes! But here it just drives crazy. Tried in several networks. Thrue 3g, home wifi. Please someone help!

Comment: Can I send you to a formatting guide?

Comment: Your problem in all cases is that you are storing your sockets as local variables within the method so as soon as the method exits the sockets cease to exist.  You need to store them as properties on your classes

Comment: Not the case. As i tried both. Like this as variables and as properties. This was just ripped from example from ray wenderlich. And in second case if you look properly they are properties and i store them. Look for self.tempSocket

Comment: @Paulw11 in second case i pass there properties to method

Comment: You do pass in a socket, but you immediately reassign a new socket to that variable - even though it is a parameter, it is still a local variable, so it will be released as soon as the class method exits.  I don't see 'self.' anywhere

Comment: I have created a sample project using GCDAsyncSocket - https://github.com/paulw11/SocketDemo/tree/master

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah - integrated~! Works!!! Thanks Man!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I can see from all of your various attempts is that you are storing the socket in a local variable - this means that once the method exits it will be released and no communications will be possible on that socket.

You need to store your socket references in `strong` properties.

I have created an example application using CocoaAsyncSocket that demonstrates listening for connections and making a connection along with tracking the connection state through properties holding the sockets.

It is available here https://github.com/paulw11/SocketDemo